# Tracking Metadata

Tags: jquery, html, metadata

I'm writing a chess program with JQuery and I want to keep track of the chess squares (TD's in a table).  I figured I would attach metadata to the square TDs.

What is a good standard to follow when attaching metadata to a table element?

custom attributes?
adding classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery, you can use the [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method, as it was already pointed out in the comment.

In general, however, metadata attributes in the DOM should have a name starting with 
`data-`:

```
<div id="stuff" data-mykey="myvalue"/>
```

See the [w3c spec on custom data attributes](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/global-attributes.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes).

Comment: attributes are out, even though I just learned you can attach an object to an attribute, it causes memory leaks in IE.  $.data it is..  FYI:  http://forum.jquery.com/topic/when-to-use-attr-vs-data